# Jruby-OpenSSL jruby-openssl-0.7.6.1

Tags: ssl, jruby-openssl

I have following environment:

- Jruby 1.6.7
- Rail 2.3.5
- jruby-openssl-0.7.6.1

I use warbler to create `.war` file and deploy on IBM Websphere Application Server.

IBM WAS has enabled FIPS recently, which caused following error when Application starts:

> Java::JavaLang::IllegalArgumentException
>   Only TLS protocol can be enabled in FIPS mode

I am looking forward to get some resolution of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to examine the backtrace to determine where the unsupported cipher is being originated.   The web server and the application are not implementing the same list of supported ciphers.